# AOT compiled code throws error - No provider for t

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angular2-aot, aot

I am getting the following error when I run my angular application. Front end is in angular and back-end uses spring.

```
build.js:1 **EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for t!
Error: No provider for t!**

at e [as constructor] (http://localhost:8080/xo-as/ng/build.js:1:59315)

at e [as constructor] (http://localhost:8080/xo-as/ng/build.js:1:60416)
at new e (http://localhost:8080/xo-as/ng/build.js:1:60744)
at t._throwOrNull (http://localhost:8080/xo-as/ng/build.js:1:71064)
at t._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:8080/xo-as/ng/build.js:1:71402)
at t._getByKey (http://localhost:8080/xo-as/ng/build.js:1:70782)
at t.get (http://localhost:8080/xo-as/ng/build.js:1:69150)
at e.get (http://localhost:8080/xo-as/ng/build.js:1:126499)
at e.t.injectorGet (http://localhost:8080/xo-as/ng/build.js:1:152798)
at e.get (
```

When I researched online for solutions I came across few posts where they mentioned it is because of some CookieOptions.

In the following link, they have suggested some solutions as well.

https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie/issues/37

And I tried the following:

```
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service';

import { CookieService, CookieOptions } from 'angular2-cookie/core';
```

When I build I am getting an error message saying 'CookieService' is not exported by 'node_modules/angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service.js'

What am I supposed to do to import it properly?
Please let me know if I need to provide any other information?

Edit :
I am able to import the CookieOptions now using the following

```
 import { CookieService, CookieOptions } from 'ngx-cookie';
```

But still when I run the application I am getting the error

```
Error: No provider for t! at e [as constructor]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`angular2-cookie` is deprecated. You should use [ngx-cookie](https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie).

Comment: Yes I installed ngx cookie also..but how to import the cookieoptions using ngx-cookie?

Comment: `import { CookieService, CookieOptions } from 'ngx-cookie';` ?

Comment: Yes I tried these. And I have edited the question with what all I tried. Still it is not importing.

Comment: @ Ludovic Guillaume  I am able to import it now...but still I get the error message while running the application.